# Table with logarithmic spacing

Tags: matrix, logarithmic-scale, table

I am looking for a simple way to build a matrix of the form:

```
Table[{x,x^2},{xmin,xmax,?}]
```

but with a kind of logarithmic spacing from `xmin` to `xmax`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `Table[{x, x^2}, {x, PowerRange[1, 64, 2]}]`?

Comment: As mentioned above, use ```PowerRange``` or ```PowerSubdivide```: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PowerSubdivide/